# Adding Proxy configuration in Angular library

Tags: angular, typescript, proxy, code-reuse, angular-library

I have converting an existing application to library. All goes well till now. The problem I am facing is I want to add proxy configurations in my library project.

Can anyone guide me how can we add proxy in library?

Thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you're talking about API proxy.

you can add in `proxy.conf.json`, all request to /api will be redirect to htts://YOUR_API.com.

```
 {
  "/api": {
    "target": "http://targetIP:targetPort",
    "secure": false,
    "pathRewrite": {"^/api" : targeturl/api},
    "changeOrigin": true,
    "logLevel": "debug"
  }
}
```

after that you change your package.json, make "start": `"ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json"`

Comment: Thankyou for your answer .Yes I need API proxy to be done. In normal angular application I have done that already, but as I mentioned I need to do the same in angular library, so doing ng serve with proxy dosen't work in library!

Comment: can you mention your package.json file in your answere